# Why is this downcast not allowed in java?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, downcast

Let's say I have a superclass of `Animal`, and a subclass of `Dog`.

We can upcast by saying:

```
Animal a = new Dog();
```

We CANNOT downcast by saying:

```
Dog b = new Animal();
```

So I do understand that an animal does not HAVE to be a dog. But, why would having an animal "blueprint" in a dog container throw an exception? Because Dog inherits methods from Animal, when we take this animal and put it into a dog container, we know Dog inherits/overrides all methods that Animal has, so why does Java not allow this?

Thank you!

Comment: Think about it, when you say animal you can't automatically assume its a dog. but you could the other way around

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Dog b = new Animal();
b.Woof();
```

Animal has no interface/method called Woof().  It does not know how to behave like a dog, but all dogs know how to behave like an animal.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: because a dog is an animal, but an animal is not necessarily a dog.

Slightly longer answer: if you were able to do that, you could call `Dog` methods on an `Animal` object that does not necessarily define those methods.

Answer (score 1):

Although we know that Dog includes all methods of Animal, we don't know that Animal includes all methods of Dog.

Consider for instance if Dog adds a method bark(). We should be able to call bark() on any object of type Dog; but if we can store an Animal there, we can store any type of Animal, say a Cat. Then we'd find ourselves asking a Cat to bark(), and something would go very wrong.

We can say that a Dog *is an* Animal, and a Cat *is an* Animal, but we can't say that an Animal *is a* Dog, or that a Cat *is a* Dog. Therefore if our variable "is a Dog", storing an Animal there wouldn't make sense.